# Can't place a WKInterfaceButton underneath another one in watchOS storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode-storyboard, watchos

I'm building a storyboard for my watchOS app in Xcode 13.0, and attempted to place a new WKInterfaceButton underneath an existing one.

The new button refused to go beneath the other one. I dragged it underneath the other one multiple times, I deleted the new one and replaced it with another, yet it wouldn't go down.

The storyboard should be laid out as followed:

Label (placement already set up)

Button (placement already set up)

New Button (being annoying)

How would I be able to place it underneath the other button?

Link to video showing the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzdv1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the 'Attributes Inspector' for both buttons to make sure the alignment is set correctly.

If the Refresh button is set to bottom, other elements will always 'float' above.

[image: Attribute Inspector showing alignment settings]

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much!